# Where array = value?

Tags: mysql, sql

It is very difficult to ask this question without giving a proper scenario, so here it goes. I have a MySQL database table with a field that stores an array of numbers. Like so...

```
id - values
1  - 1,2,3
```

I need to query against this. Like...

```
select * from table where values = 3
```

How to accomplish this?

If this was answered, please point me to the answer because I was unable to find it.

Please note that this is pure MySQL

Comment: What's the data type of `values`

Comment: Thanks for asking but it seems FIND_IN_SET did the trick. I will update my post accordingly if this does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `FIND_IN_SET` function.

```
CREATE TABLE `table`(
  id int,
  `values` varchar(50)
);


 insert into `table` values (1 ,'1,2,3');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from `table` where FIND_IN_SET('3',`values`)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0b8f1/1/0)**:

```
| id | values |
|----|--------|
|  1 |  1,2,3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `values` RLIKE '(^|,)3($|,)'
```

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer this over `FIND_IN_SET`? It's not as clear IMHO.

Comment: No, I think `FIND_IN_SET()` is preferable, just offering up another idea since it's the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7140f189f8c9da072afe4f1985ea9af9